# JPQL CAST WITH HANA = CLOSE, found '('

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, hana, jql

I'm trying to do a cast in my sql query hana.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE 
ORDER BY CAST(JSON_VALUE(MYTABLE .data, '$.total') AS DECIMAL(38, 4))
```

This code works perctly when perfomed in database, but when I try this code in JPQL I get this error.

```
expecting CLOSE, found '('
```

I had already tried to change the dialect of hana, but i got the same error, any ideia how to fix?